# Searching File In Directory

Tags: c, file

I need to search for a certain `file`.txt in a `folder` directory, and I was instructed to specifically use binary search. I do understand the idea of implementing binary search to find the specific file wanted, however, I worked this piece of code which seems to give the same result, although it didn't actually "search" the file (it opens it directly from the directory).

Here it is:

```
DIR *userFolder = opendir ("./users");
if (userFolder == NULL) printf ("No Folder Found\n");
char userFileToSearch[25];
sprintf (userFileToSearch, "%s.txt", username);
char userFileToOpen[30] = {"./users/"};
sprintf (userFileToOpen, "%s%s", userFileToOpen, userFileToSearch);
FILE *userData = fopen (userFileToOpen, "r");
```

*username is the given filename.

Does this actually fulfill what's asked from searching file in a directory (without binary search, though)?

Comment: I don't see how binary search would help here. Ask your instructor why it would.